# List all kerberized SPN's in Linux

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, spn

Is there a way to list/show all SPN's in an kerberized AD using a Linux Client?

In Windows one can use `setspn -T <domain> -Q */*` to get them. Is there something similar? Haven't found anything yet.

Or is it even possible? Of course I request a TGT with my Linux client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear on what you are asking, do you just want a list of all SPNs in an Active Directory domain/forest from a Linux box? You can use ldapsearch for SPNs via the servicePrincipalName attribute.

Comment: Well in Windows I can use the setstpn -T <domain> -Q */* command to check for what services I may request a ticket. I want to do the same in Linux, being authenticated to Kerberos, having a valid TGT, which I want to use to get a TGS for a service, I may not know the name, or just for all services. I can use kvno to request a ticket for a service of course, but I need to discover the name somehow. Thats what I try to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ldapsearch tool from the openldap-client package of your favourite distro and then you can query SPN attributes like

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -H ldap://example.local -D "administrator@example.local" -W -b "dc=example,dc=local,dc=com" "servicePrincipalName=*" sAMAccountName servicePrincipalName
```